# Using Java Reflection for ActivityTaskManager (Android)

Tags: android, reflection

I am learning about Java reflection and trying to access a method `getInstance` that is hidden using @hide (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/core/java/android/app/ActivityTaskManager.java) line 149.

However, I keep getting NoSuchMethodException.

```
        val taskManager = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityTaskManager")

        val myInstance = taskManager.getMethod("getInstance")
        myInstance.setAccessible(true)
        val retval = myInstance.invoke(null)
```

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

An example to invoke a method by reflection ( you need to pass the instance of object and the types of parameters )

```java
 public class MyClass {
     // non-static method
     public String method1(String param1){
         return param1.toUpperCase();
     }
     // static method
     public static String method2(String param1){
          return param1.toLowerCase();
     }
}
```

Invoke by reflection

```java
try {
    // calling non-static method
    MyClass objectInstance = MyClass.class.getConstructor().newInstance();

    Method  methodToInvoke = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(
        "method1", // method name
        String.class // type first parameter
    );

    String returnMethod = (String) methodToInvoke.invoke(
            objectInstance, // class instance
            "valueParam1"   // first param value
        );

    System.out.println(returnMethod); // VALUEPARAM1;

    // calling static method

    Method  method2ToInvoke = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(
        "method2", // method name
        String.class // type first parameter
    );

    String returnMethod2 = (String) method2ToInvoke.invoke(
            null, // instance not required on static methods
            "VALUEPARAM1"   // first param value
        );

    System.out.println(returnMethod2); // valueparam1;

} catch (ReflectiveOperationException | IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> `MyClass.class` is same as `Class.forName("MyClass")` and same as `objectMyClass.getClass()`

Comment: Hi

I am calling a static method that does not take parameters so I think my code is ok? I read in another post (forgot the link) that Google may have restricted the calling of hidden methods?

Comment: yeh.. it should work only doing that. eg. `Arrays.toString(ActivityTaskManager.class.getDeclaredMethods())` , try to check how your dependencie has been added in your classpath, may there is some way to put the source in your build to get code when running.